# Using Synonym in SQL Server 2008 R2 (Create and detect existence of a table)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, create-table, synonym

Is there any way to CREATE a table on SQL Server 2008 R2 by referencing the table name with a synonym? Also how can I detect if any object (the base object) is existing in the database by its synonym?

I've recently discovered that you can create a synonym for an object that does not even exist in the database. It is kind of weird. But it might just be VERY useful for an implementation I'm trying to do.

So if I need to create a table named `dbo.Customer`, I want to do the following-

```sql
/* The table dbo.Customer has not been created in the database yet */
CREATE SYNONYM Customer_Synonym FOR dbo.Customer

/* I know the lines below will give the wrong result (the object_id detection part)
 * and an error (the create table part), cause I've tried it.
 * I want to know if there is any simple work around for this
 */
IF OBJECT_ID(N'Customer_Synonym') IS NOT NULL
CREATE TABLE Customer_Synonym
(
    cust_id INT NOT NULL
    , cust_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
    ...
    ...
);
```

Any help or suggestion will be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you can't create a table with the same name as a synonym afaik

Comment: @JeremyC. I'm not trying to do that either. I want to create a table that has entirely different name than its synonym. But I want to create it by referencing the synonym. Like, the table I want to create is `dbo.customer`, but the synonym is named `Customer_Synonym`.

Comment: then why not just do create table dbo.customer?

Comment: @JeremyC. It is actually a long story. This query is actually a part of a C# program where the table name is configurable. I know there are lot of ways to implement this, but I have been assigned to do R&D on synonym implementation. I've been trying a lot of methods but getting stuck at some point.
So I need to keep Synonyms in my query and use them to create tables.

Comment: at some point you're going to have to give the actual table name for the creation though (however you could just pass the table name through application logic), afaik you can't create a table and then name it later (which I think is what you are trying to do here no?), you can however create a table with a randomly generated name, save that generated name and then use sp_rename on it later: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/Library/aa337520.aspx

Comment: @JeremyC. I'm not actually renaming. The scenario is like this - <br/> I have been given a table name (not named) `dbo.Customer` which has not been created yet in the database. I am creating a synonym against that table name `Customer_Synonym`. Notice, the table has still not been created, just the synonym has been. Now I wanna use this synonym to create that table with the given name `dbo.Customer`.
<br/>
Hope I could explain the situation correctly.

Comment: so what stops you from creating the table first and then creating the synonym and using it?

Comment: @JeremyC. I guess I wanted to create the synonym on the table name first and then use it all through the project. I was trying to find a work around for this problem. Are you suggesting not to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure if I get what you mean but if you are creating the synonym beforehand, you already know what the table name is going to be right? why not just create the table then and there instead of going through the trouble of creating a complicated workaround that tbh I don't even know is going to work anyway